# Using sidekiq with ActiveJob is creating issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, sidekiq

I am trying to use sidekiq to send emails as background job in my application. 
but when i execute command: `bundle exec sidekiq -C config/sidekiq.yml`
It shows error in command prompt. [image]
I have sidekiq.yml as :

```
:concurrency: 25
:pidfile: ./tmp/pids/sidekiq.pid
:logfile: ./log/sidekiq.log
:queues:
   - default
```

Can you tell how to remove this error. I have started redis client and server exe

Comment: `bundle up sidekiq`

Comment: not working still